# How to Spool UTF-8 format data in Oracle database into text file

Tags: text, utf-8, oracle10g

How to Spool UTF-8 format data in Oracle database into text file with all UTF-8 Chars comming porperly. 
    UTF-8 Characters example Chinese characters. 
     I am trying to spool data from oracle data base which is UTF-8 enabled and trying to spool the same data into txt or cvs.Instead of the chinese charcters i am getting ????.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the file is correct but your file viewer cannot render the characters for some reason. Check with a hex editor whether the UTF-8 is appearing correctly.

fileformat.info is great for checking things like this (e.g. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2fd3/index.htm)